# Pass variable to new form with Datatable and Listbox

Tags: vb.net

I am currently trying to write an application like address book. Listbox works properly, it shows everything corretly. But I need to pass id of chosen listbox item to another form. I got code like this in Form2:

```
Private myTable As New DataTable()
Public Sub LoadXml(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    With myTable.Columns
        .Add("DisplayValue", GetType(String))
        .Add("HiddenValue", GetType(Integer))
    End With
    myTable.DefaultView.Sort = "DisplayValue ASC"

    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayValue"
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "HiddenValue"
    ListBox1.DataSource = myTable
    Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
    doc.Load("c:\address.xml")
    Dim xmlName As Xml.XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("name")
    Dim xmlSurname As Xml.XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("surname")
    Dim xmlId As Xml.XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("id")
    For i As Integer = 0 To xmlName.Count - 1
        Dim nazwa As String = xmlName(i).FirstChild.Value + " " + xmlSurname(i).FirstChild.Value
        myTable.Rows.Add(nazwa, xmlId(i).FirstChild.Value)
        MsgBox(myTable.Rows(i).Item(1).ToString)
    Next i
    ListBox1.Sorted = True
End Sub
```

Later in the code I have event:

```
Public Sub ListBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick

End Sub
```

I would like to know how can I call id from DataTable for selected listbox item. I hope u understand what I mean since my english is not perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added the XML value `id` to the data table column `HiddenValue` and you have assigned `HiddenValue` as the `ValueMember` for the listbox, once a record is selected in the listbox, id will be available in the listbox's `[SelectedValue][1]` member. For example:

```
Public Sub ListBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick
    MsgBox("Selected Id: " & ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried a global variable to hold what you want and then reference it? Also if you have a column declared you can get this by referencing the selected columns value...